# VSCode JSDoc Multiline for Intellisense

Tags: visual-studio-code, jsdoc

I am looking to have JSON examples in my documentation, which in turn will have JSON examples in my intellisense for VScode.

I have tried every trick in the book that I can think of, is this possible to do with line breaks and things that would make the JSON readable? I cannot get this to work in VScode no matter what I do, it takes out white space and makes one line.

I try to do:

```
/**
 * {
 *   "JSONData":"not going to format like this"
 * }
 */
functionToDescribe()
```

this of course will end up in intellisense like so...

```
{ "JSONData":"not going to format like this" }
```

This is ok with small examples, but I would like to have a bit larger (still small) simple examples. There are other reasons I really want line breaks, not just JSON, I just want my text to be cleaner in my comments in general.

I will also take different examples of how other people document it. I am really looking to make my JS code easier to know what to expect the function to accept, return and use in operation before using it.

**EDIT:**
I stumbled across this link: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/30062

which now I understand that formatting works when you look at the declaration of the function or item, but not when you go to use it.

the following markup code works great when I hover over the function name, but when I use it like normal it is all on one line and worthless

````
    /** This is a description  
     * with each line  
     * on it's own  
     * 
     * @example Test 
     * ```javascript
     * let valueReturned = false;
     * jest.fn(() => {
     *           if (!valueReturned) {
     *             valueReturned = true;
     *             return value;
     *             //no idea why it requires me to have so many spaces...
     *           }
     * });
     * ```
     */ 
     functionTest()  //When hovering over this, it looks great

     functionTest(  //at this point intellisense pops up and is worthless
````

I believe this is a bug or simply bad design, maybe I will put in a feature request, if it doesn't already exist.

I will keep this question open in case someone else has any suggestions or possible work arounds.

**EDIT:**

Good news, it looks like this was a bug and after searching for quite a while, it seems this was fixed just this month and will be with the September release!

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/1920

I will close this now and leave this up for anyone else who was having troubles with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a bug for the intellisense, which has been corrected as of 4 days ago, so it should be released soon, so if you can get the "hover" to look as you want, it should translate to the intellisense when the fix drops.

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/1920